# Why does this iterative list-growing code give IndexError: list assignment index out of range? How can I repeatedly add (append) elements to a list?

Tags: python, list, exception

I tried writing some code like:

```
i = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
j = []
k = 0

for l in i:
    j[k] = l
    k += 1
```

But I get an error message that says `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`, referring to the `j[k] = l` line of code. Why does this occur? How can I fix it?

Comment: `append` is the right solution for your use case, however there's an insert method on python list which can insert directly to the i'th position in list. `j.insert(k, l)`

Comment: May I ask, why would not OP's solution work? Why use append?

Answer (score 399, accepted):

`j` is an empty list, but you're attempting to write to element `[0]` in the first iteration, which doesn't exist yet.

Try the following instead, to add a new element to the end of the list:

```
for l in i:
    j.append(l)
```

Of course, you'd never do this in practice if all you wanted to do was to copy an existing list. You'd just do:

```
j = list(i)
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use the Python list like an array in other languages, then you could pre-create a list with its elements set to a null value (`None` in the example below), and later, overwrite the values in specific positions:

```
i = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
j = [None] * len(i)
#j == [None, None, None, None, None, None]
k = 0

for l in i:
   j[k] = l
   k += 1
```

The thing to realise is that a `list` object will not allow you to assign a value to an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. I didn't know which one to praise as there are three almost same answers. This is most descriptive I think. Cheers

Comment: I can see that this can be very confusing for those coming from other languages like PHP or C.   j is a type of list, not an array. With list type, I don't think this is subscriptable.  Very confusing if coming from other languages.

Comment: @Nguaial The list type is subscriptable, but you can only access elements that already exist - you can't create an element by attempting to write to an index that is out of range.  j[0] = "foo" will work if the list already has at least one element.

Comment: I wonder about reasons behind this design decision...

Comment: after using the append it show the error cannot assign to function call

Comment: @usmanimtiaz you need to initialise the variables i j and k using the code in the original question. i = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
j = []
k = 0

Answer (score 66):

Your other option is to initialize `j`:

```
j = [None] * len(i)
```

Answer (score 30):

Do `j.append(l)` instead of `j[k] = l` and avoid `k` at all.

Comment: A shorter (more Pythonic?) way might be `j+=[l]`

Comment: @BlaXpirit: It will put burden to the garbage collector, I think.

Comment: @BalXpirit: Given that is only saves a few characters (especially since you need to add spaces for it to be acceptable) and that `.append` is by far more common (perhaps for a reason - I think it's slightly easier to comprehend), not really superior in any way. (Edit @khachik: No, `+=` modifies in-place)

Answer (score 18):

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
j = [l for l in i]
```

or make a copy of it using the statement:

```
j = i[:]
```

Comment: that second construction is neat

Comment: If the only goal is to copy the list, you can simply say j = list(i)
I think the question is more about the behaviour of lists, rather than specifically needing a way to copy elements.

Answer (score 11):

```
j.append(l)
```

Also avoid using lower-case "L's" because it is easy for them to be confused with 1's

Comment: In a monospace font, `l` is quite different than `1`

Comment: To me it's not.

Answer (score 8):

I think the Python method **insert** is what you're looking for:

Inserts element x at position i.
list.insert(i,x)

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
# array.insert(index, element)
array.insert(1,20)

print(array)

# prints [1,20,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: There is no point using `insert` when `append` was provided specifically for this purpose.

Comment: On a point of information, your code in fact prints `[1, 20, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: You inserted at index 1, displacing indices 1 and onwards. The inserted value does not end up at index 2. Iist.insert() is only really needed when you don’t want to add the item at the end of the list; the question here does exactly that so list.append() is preferable.

Comment: Actually why I answer this question like that I am also suprised :D Do not know what I thought :) This is exactly "list.append()" which is the accepted answer. I think it helps people or give an idea to solve their problems so it gets 5 hits.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a dictionary (similar to an associative array) for j

```
i = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
j = {} #initiate as dictionary
k = 0

for l in i:
    j[k] = l
    k += 1

print(j)
```

will print :

```
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 5, 4: 8, 5: 13}
```

Comment: For consecutive indicies starting at 0 a mapping is usually the *wrong* data structure, especially when mappings do not have slicing or reversing as they are not intended to convey any specific order.

Answer (score 2):

One more way:

```
j=i[0]
for k in range(1,len(i)):
    j = numpy.vstack([j,i[k]])
```

In this case `j` will be a numpy array

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need *extend()*

```
i=[1,3,5,7]
j=[]
j.extend(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the `append` method should be used for readibility.
Likely not recommended, I want to point out that appending also works with
slicing or list concatation. Replacing `j[k] = l`, by one of the following possibilities, would fix your problem, too:

```py
j[k:] = [l]
```

```py
j[k:] = l,
```

```py
j += l,
```

I also like to mention that appending with `j[k] = l` can work in other languages, like e.g. javascript.