# Python - Sorting High Scores from a file

Tags: python

I have a task, and it is to write a program with the following menu items (being read off a file):
1-Display High Scores
2-Add a new high score
3-Clear All high scores
4-Quit

I've got the rest working, it's just 1-Display High scores. I'm receiving syntax errors with it. The error being an InternalError: list out of range. Here is the part of the code:

```
def askUser():
Question=input('What would you like to do?\n1-Display High Scores\n2-Add A New High Score\n3-Clear All High Scores\n4-Quit\nPlease choose a number:')
if Question=='1':
    myFile=open('Scores.txt','r')
    column=[]
    for line in myFile:
        column.append(int(line.split("\t")[3]))
    column.sort()
    print(column)
    myFile.close()
    askUser()
```

It might still not make sense from here... yet. However here is my full code:

```
def askUser():
Question=input('What would you like to do?\n1-Display High Scores\n2-Add A New High Score\n3-Clear All High Scores\n4-Quit\nPlease choose a number:')
if Question=='1':
    myFile=open('Scores.txt','r')
    column=[]
    for line in myFile:
        column.append(int(line.split("\t")[3]))
    column.sort()
    print(column)
    myFile.close()
    askUser()
if Question=='2':
    Name=input('What is your name:')
    Date=input('What is the date:')
    Score=input('What was your high score:')
    myFile=open('Scores.txt','a')
    myFile.write(("\n"+"{},{},{}").format(Name, Date, Score))
    myFile.close()
    askUser()
if Question=='3':
    myFile=open('Scores.txt','r+')
    myFile.truncate()
    myFile.close()
    print('File Cleared')
    askUser()
if Question=='4':
   print('Quiting...')
```

Sorry if I am not being clear. I need to Display High scores (Option 1) from the file **Scores.txt**. I already have a few sample scores written in there, if you need to get them too, try this code:

```
Name=input('What is your name:')
Date=input('What is the date:')
Score=input('What was your high score:')
myFile=open('Scores.txt','a')
myFile.write(("\n"+"{},{},{}").format(Name, Date, Score))
myFile.close()
```

Comment: Firstly, correct indentation is needed.

Secondly, try to include  the full error message you are getting. Also, 
you might find this of use: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran Code:

```
    column.append(int(line.split("\t")[3]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I believe you're not splitting on the right criteria. You generate the score file using commas as the..uhh separator.. but then ask it to split based on \t which is tabs, I believe. Change that to a comma. Also, python indexes start with 0. So set the 3(refers to the 4th item) to a 2(refers to the 3rd item).

Additionally, having a blank line at the beginning of the score.txt(suppose you clear the scores and add them creates the problem).

Do something like this:

```
    for line in myFile:
        if line == "\n":
            this = "doesnothing"
        else:
            column.append(int(line.split(",")[2]))
```

Also searching the returned error helps:
[Python: IndexError: list index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256013/python-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range)

Comment: Hmm... I'm still getting the same Index out of range error.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have helped me incredibly!

Answer (score 1):

You only mentioned that you got 'syntax errors' with your code but didn't actually say which errors you got, but based on the code snippets I'd say that you didn't get the indentation right: there should be an indented block after `def`.