# In Django/Python how to handle exception - list index out of range for empty table?

Tags: python, django

My problem is that when my Database is empty I am getting this error

> IndexError at / list index out of range

```
>  period = Period.objects.all()
>     try:
>         period_current = [obj for obj in period if ((obj.is_current)==True)]
>                     total_payment_period_current_dict = LeasePayment.objects.filter(payment_date__range=[period_current[0].start_date,
> period_current[0].end_date]).aggregate(Sum('amount')) ...
>         total_payment_period_current = total_payment_period_current_dict['amount__sum']
>     except ValueError:
>         raise Http404("Can't perform calculation for total_payment_period_current, check data ")
```

I hoped I can handle it with exeption to give meaningful error , but it doesn't work. What I can do to give meaningful error . Or ideally to avoid this exception all together in case of empty tables?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle this error then I would suggest putting a check for length of list.

```
try:
    period_current = [obj for obj in period if ((obj.is_current)==True)]
    if len(period_current == 0) {
       raise Http404("Can't perform calculation for total_payment_period_current, check data ") 
    }
    total_payment_period_current_dict = LeasePayment.objects.filter(payment_date__range=
                                  [period_current[0].start_date,
                period_current[0].end_date]).aggregate(Sum('amount')) 
         total_payment_period_current = total_payment_period_current_dict['amount__sum']
     except ValueError:
         raise Http404("Can't perform calculation for total_payment_period_current, check data ")
```

This is a wrong exception for your case. You might want to use `IndexError` exception instead of `ValueError` exception.

```
except IndexError:
    raise Http404("Can't perform calculation for" +
                  "total_payment_period_current, check data ")
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256013/python-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range) answer might be helpful to you to understand the problem.