# how to change element in 2D array in python

Tags: python

I intend to change the value of boolean array in 2D from True to false, but the code does not work. The output results are the same even I use statement b[r][c] = False. Could someone help me on this, thanks.

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[True for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)])
print(b)

for r in b:
    for c in r:
        b[r][c] = False
print(b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the indices of `b` to change elements, not the elements themselves. Try:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[True for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)])
print(b)

for i, r in enumerate(b):
    for j, c in enumerate(r):
        b[i,j] = False
print(b)
```

Comment: And it's worth noting b[i, j] is a little more efficient given how numpy works.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I've edited my answer to change b[i][j] to b[i,j].

Answer (score 1):

You could use broadcasting in Numpy.  (works on all elements without the for loops.)

```
a =np.array([True]*25).reshape(5,5)
b = a * False
print(b)
```

True evaluates to 1 and False evaluates to 0
so 1*0 is ... 0

Comment: This is a better answer than mine as far as efficient implementation goes, but OP should also understand how to properly edit a list/array from within a `for` loop.

Comment: I'm of the mindset that we need to abolish the for loop in libraries like numpy and pandas and so forth in that direction on the stack.  (This is a theory in progress so I'm looking for counter examples)

Comment: I appreciate being able to substitute a normal list for a numpy array and know that I don't have to reformat code that uses that list in a `for` loop. If speed is a concern, then I can do some code reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is this:

```
b[r, c] = False
```

numpy arrays work best using numpy's access methods. The other way would create a view of the array and you'd be altering the view.

EDIT: also, r, c do need to be numbers, not True / True like the other answer said. I was reading more into the question than was being asked.

Comment: This one does not work completely.   See the result

    [[False False  True  True  True]
     [ True False  True  True  True]
     [False False  True  True  True]
     [False False  True  True  True]
     [False False  True  True  True]]