# Create Optionmenu with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, optionmenu

I am pretty new to Python as well as coding in general.

I've got 42 Labels (Strings) stored in a list. 
My aim is to: for each of the 42 labels, create a Tkinter Label displaying the String and a Dropdown List (Tkinter Optionmenu).

**Two problems** occur:

- I get an index error for the list of variables (for the optionmenus), here is the output of my Console:

  > varDd[i] = StringVar(root)
  >   IndexError: list assignment index out of range
- The Canvas is Scrollable as I intended, but the content doesn't scroll with it

My complete Code:
https://codepaste.net/6jkuza

The **essential part**:

```
def createDdList():    
    del labelsDd[:]
    del listsDd[:]
        if len(labels) > 1:
            varDd = [len(labels)]
            for i,label in enumerate(labels):
#               Erstelle Labels mit den Markerlabels im scrollbaren Canvas
                labelsDd.append(Label(contentCanvas,text=label))
                labelsDd[i].pack()
#               Erstelle die Dropdown Listen im scrollbaren Canvas
                varDd[i] = StringVar(root)
                listsDd.append(OptionMenu(canvas,varDd[i],*labels))  
                listsDd[i].place(x=70,y=10+(30*i))

contentCanvas = Frame(canvas,bg='#FFFFFF')
canvas.create_window((0,375),window=contentCanvas)
```

Comment: um... when would `if 'listDd' in locals()` ever possibly be True and why on earth are you checking for membership of `locals()`?

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen: if u run the Map button a second time. However if its bad I will remove it

Comment: if you don't know what your own code is doing what kind of help are you expecting? I know the first thing I'd tell you is "know what a line of code means/does before writing other code that relies on it" so any code that is in a conditional, I'd expect you to know what the conditional means.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I removed the line of code, sincerely.
PS: still doesn't fix the other 2 issues

Comment: Ok the index error is happening because `varDd = [len(labels)]` _doesn't_ [initialize an empty lists with a certain length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size) and I think the second issue is happening because you need to call `canvas.create_window` to put the stuff in it instead of `.place`-ing the widgets inside it, I'm actually surprised that worked at all... Will need to investigate that further...

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Thanks ;)! Will work into it

Comment: you are not stupid - you are new, it happens to everybody ;)  I will ask that you edit your question putting that code in it, really hard to read from a comment.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I appreciate that, I found a solution, it was about the anchor -> I setted the offset to 350 for y now it starts with Marker label 0
So now the first issue is complete solved, box is scrollable. Thanks a lot for the hint with the create_window in the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue arrises from this like:

```
varDd = [len(labels)]
```

While this syntax is used in other languages to mean "a list with this many elements in python it is just a list with one number:

```
>>> labels = range(4)
>>> v = [len(labels)]
>>> v
[4]
```

Instead you probably want something along the lines of this:

```
>>> varDb = [None]*len(labels)
>>> varDb
[None, None, None, None]
```

Then you can index it the same way as your other lists

---

The other issue is that using `.place()` inside a canvas places it on the screen but not on the canvas space itself, to do that you need to call `canvas.create_window` so this line:

```
listsDd[i].place(x=70,y=10+(30*i))
```

would translate to this:

```
canvas.create_window(70, 10+(30*i), window = listsDd[i])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Regarding the canvas, does anything speak against my solution? Create a new frame out of the loop and fill this with the labels and OptionsMenus inside the loop?

This solved all my issues!

Comment: nothing against it at all, in fact it makes me happy when people can figure out their own solutions :)

Comment: Actually another question appeared regarding this code. 
I am using varDd[i] = StringVar(root), and I am not quite sure why I am giving it the Mainframe as an argument.

This is related to my new Problem / Question which appeared, how do I access the varDd[i] content from another function?

I am trying to avoid the usage of global variables

Comment: ok nvm, I solved with a wrapper class around the function which has the attribute varDd, so I can read it out later ;)

Comment: Don't actively avoid using global variables because people tell you "they are bad." When you learn about `class`es and the reusability of instance variables then you will understand why they are frequently preferred over globals but **always make code using the methods that make sense to you** (at least that's my motto)