# Python performance iterating through lists, numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I am working on a project where I have to loop through large arrays (lists), accessing each item by index.
Usually this involves checking each element against a condition, and thereafter potentially updating its value.

I've noticed that this is extremely slow compared to, for example, doing a similar thing in C#. Here is a sample of simply looping through arrays and reassigning each value:

C#:

```
var a = new double[10000000];
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
     a[i] = 1.0;
}      
watch.Stop();
var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
//About 40ms
```

Python:

```
a = []
for i in range(0, 10000000):
    a.append(0.0)

t1 = time.clock()

for i in range(0, 10000000):
    a[i] = 1.0

t2 = time.clock()
totalTime = t2-t1
//About 900ms
```

The python code here seems to be over 20x slower. 
I am relatively new to python so I cannot judge if this kind of performance is "normal", 
or if I am doing something horribly wrong here. I am running Anaconda as my python environment, PyCharm is my IDE.

Note: I have tried using `nditer` on numpy arrays with no significant performance increase.

Many thanks in advance for any tips!

**UPDATE:**
I've just compared the following two approaches:

```
#timeit: 43ms
a = np.random.randn(1000,1000)
a[a < 0] = 100.0

#timeit: 1650ms
a = np.random.randn(1000,1000)
for x in np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']):
    if (x < 0):
        x[...] = 100.0
```

looks like the first (vectorized) approach is the way to go here...

Comment: Python-loops are slower than it's counterparts in many other languages. Either vectorize your operations with numpy (depends on your operations) or speed up loops with [cython](http://cython.org/) or [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) (cython is also used within scipy and even more in scikit-learn; popular scientific libs).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size This question might help. Is creating a list with "append" inefficient somehow?

Comment: `nditer` does not promise performance.

Comment: What you call the first-approach here, ```a[a<0] = 100.0``` is what is often referred to *vectorization* within numpy.

Comment: Thanks @sascha, I will look into what exactly vectorization refers to

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `numpy` you should use the `numpy` array type and then take advantage of `numpy` functions and broadcasting:

If your specific need is to assign `1.0` to all elements, there is a specific function for that in `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.ones(10_000_000)
```

For a somewhat more general approach, where you first define the array and then assign all the different elements:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.empty(10_000_000)
a[:] = 1.0 # This uses the broadcasting
```

By default, the `np.array` is of type `double` so all elements will be `double`s.

Also, as a side note, using `time` for performance measurement is not optimal, since that will use the "wall clock time" and can be heavily affected by other programs running in the computer. Consider looking into the `timeit` module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, especially the comment about the timeit module! Cheers

Comment: Why is this answer down-voted? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score -1):

Python has a bunch of great ways to iterate on structures.  There is good chance, if you find yourself using what I call `C` style looping:

```
for i in range(0, 10000000):
    a = [1.0] * 10000000
```

... you are likely doing it wrong.

In my quick testing this is 40x faster than the above:

```
a = [1.0] * 10000000
```

Even a basic list comprehension is 3x faster:

```
a = [1.0 for i in range(0, 10000000)]
```

And as mentioned in comments, [cython](http://cython.org/), [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) and [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html), can all be used to provide various speedups for this sort of work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've just tried a[a<0] = 100.0
 where a is a numpy array, and I seem to be getting at least a bit of a performance increase.

Comment: I don't understand your comparison. You are doing two different things.