# How to create an array of lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Does anyone know how to create an array of lists in python?

For example, if I want the final structure to contain data where the 1st dimension is fixed but the 2nd dimension varies:

index 0: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

index 1: [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

index 2: [4, 3, 2, 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just called a list of lists

```
x=[[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],[4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I initialize it so that the 1st dimension is fixed? For example, if I wanted to initialize it as length 13 so I can access a certain index later.

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size. Thanks for your help!