# How do I set an array to the length of a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a very amateur programmer, and I want to make an array full of 0s, that is the length of a number.

How do I do that?

Comment: `[0] * num` - but note that for array of arrays (or other mutable objects) you'd need `[[] for _ in range(num)]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an empty list in python with certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size)

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do that

i=7;
arr=[0]*i;

Answer (score 0):

Create a list and use a for loop to fill it with 0's.

```
my_list = []

for _ in range(n):
  my_list.append(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: a = [0] * 7     # if length is 7

In [2]: a
Out[2]: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```