# Python equivalent of Ruby Array block instantiation?

Tags: python, ruby

In Ruby I could say something like:

```rb
Array.new(5) { SomeClass.new }
# => [#<SomeClass:0x00007fb9bf053ba8>, #<SomeClass:0x00007fb9bf053b80>, #<SomeClass:0x00007fb9bf053b58>, #<SomeClass:0x00007fb9bf053b30>, #<SomeClass:0x00007fb9bf053b08>]
```

Is there an equivalent syntax in python?

**Edit:**

Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002), because this question asks for equivalent syntax and asks how to generate a list using an anonymous function (or similar), not how to build an empty list.

Comment: `|i|` has no purpose here; it can be left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension for that:

```
[SomeClass() for _ in range(5)]
```

or if your use case allows it you can get an iterator with:

```
map(lambda _: SomeClass(), range(5))
```