# Is this an ideal way to automate object instantiation using functions?

Tags: python, function, oop

I'm trying to design a function in Python which instantiates a number of objects based on a user input. I've derived one which works, and it looks as follows

```
class Node(): ...

def initialise():
    binary_tree=[]
    opt=int(input("Enter the number of nodes you want\n"))
    for i in range(opt):
        a=Node()
        binary_tree.append(a)
```

although I'm not sure that this is the ideal way to do this.

Is there a better way of programming a function such as the one I've described, or is the above method sufficient for efficiency and clarity purposes?

Any responses are appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't need to assign `Node` to `a`. Just directly do `binary_tree.append(Node())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an empty list in python with certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work ok.

There are other options to format it; for example, you could use list comprehension, which might be slightly faster than using `.append()` and also uses slightly less code:

```
def initialise():
    opt = int(input("Enter the number of nodes you want\n"))

    return [
        Node()
        for _ in range(opt)]
```

Careful: this (as well as your version) code might raise a `ValueError` if the uses enters a string that cannot be converted to `int`.