# Creating and declaring list in class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a list within a class and then declaring elements in that list.
I don't even know if this is the right way for python. I have some java background.

I didn't add 10 elements in the list manually because I feel creating a dynamic list will be more useful.

```
class Levels:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = "A"
        self.size = [] # trying to create a list for 10 elements. 
        self.makespace(self.size) # running this method to create 10 spaces and then declare them. 


    def makespace(self, size):
        for i in range(0,10):
            if(size[i] == None):
                size[i] = "free"
                print(i)
           else:
            print("Didn't work")
            print(i)



test = Levels()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an empty list in python with certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size)

Comment: In `__init__`, you can initialize the list using `self.size = ['free'] * 10`. Lists in python are dynamic, so initializing this way is the same as what your code is trying to do.

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You rarely need to do this with python. Why do you need this — maybe there's a more Pythonic way?

Comment: I too think this is an XY problem. You should rely on methods to dynamically add (e.g. `.append` or `.extend`) to your list as you need it. Rarely should you initialize a list with "empty" values. Or, are you coming from a language like javascript, where indexing into an array out of bounds gives you some null-like value (e.g. `undefined`). EDIT: re-reading, if you are coming from Java, you should use this like `List` interface, not like primitive arrays, where you declare some fixed size. Python does not generally work this way, learn to do it the Python way to make writing Python easier

Comment: @MarkMeyer I am trying to create a class which stores a 'type' and list/array which stores numbers for multiple entries. For example type = maths, size = [marks of different students] so this class should store marks for all students.

Comment: @HinaSatti just `.append` to the list, you don't need to worry about the size of the list. A list is not like a primitive array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in here.

```py
            if(size[i] == None):
                size[i] = "free"
                print(i)
```

At this moment, size is empty, it doesn't contain any elements so why are you
checking `size[i] == None`?
You probably think that a python list behaves like an array in Java where it initializes everything with null? Even though here you are not declaring the size of the list inside the **init** constructor, so I'm curious how you thought of that.

Your code should look like this:

```py
class Levels:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = "A"
        self.size = [] # trying to create a list for 10 elements. 
        self.makespace(self.size) # running this method to create 10 spaces and then declare them. 


    def makespace(self, size):

        #This will fill the emty list with 10 None(null) values
        for i in range(0,10):
            size.append(None)



test = Levels()
```

Also a bonus:

```py
class Levels:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = "A"
        self.size = []

        #Notice that I'm not passing self as an argument when I call makespace()

        self.makespace()


    def makespace(self):

        #This will fill the emty list with 10 None(null) values
        for i in range(0,10):
            self.size.append(None)



test = Levels()
```

Self is the **this** keyword in python, the difference is that in Python you need to pass it as an argument **only when declaring methods, not when you call them** and also you can name it whatever you want!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot this makes a lot sense to me compared to other answers :)

Answer (score 0):

This code won't work because `size[i]` does not exist. Instead use `size.append(...)`. Also you should pass a number to `makespace` so that you can make space for an arbitrary number of items.

```py
class Levels:

    def __init__(self, kind='A', size=10):
        self.kind = kind
        self.size = [ 0 for _ in range(10) ]
```

These slight changes make your code more robust and more pythonic.

**First but the least important** is that `type` is a builtin-method (also a class and also a type) so `kind` is often substituted.

**Second** You can pass default arguments to the constructor (or any function) as you should generally avoid having constants inside functions like that. Here you can arbitrarily set a `Level`'s kind, as well as the initial space required.

**Third** Using list-comprehension you can create a list of arbitrary size (or elements). The syntax is

`[ expression for args in iterable ]`

which allows for any expression to be generated based on arguments passed from an iterable. Read more about list comprehension and other datastructure [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

As for your `makespace` you shouldnt really need it, however you could change the implementation so you can allocate more space (using `self.size.append(...)`) or overwriting currently used space.

Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have 10 free spaces in the list upon initializing, change

```
self.size = []
```

to

```
self.size = [“free”] * 10
```

If you want to start with an empty list and add 10 free spaces in your makespace loop, simply use

```
self.size.append(“free”)
```

Also, you really don’t need to pass size to makespace.  Since you’re already passing self, I would just reference self.size from inside the makespace function.

Comment: these statements should be comments.

Comment: @babaliaris I fixed it.  Posted answer from my phone since the solution is very simple.