# Changing the number of elements in a list to a number N

Tags: python, list

We provide you with a number `N`.

Create a list then, using a loop, populate the list with `N` elements. Set each list element to the index multiplied by 10.

The easiest way would probably be to change `len(numbers)` to equal the value of N, but I know I can't do it through brute force, i.e.: `len(numbers) = N`.
Here is what I have tried.

```
import sys    
N= int(sys.argv[1])    
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Maybe looking at python's [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an empty list in python with certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO is not a code-writing service. Please provide what you have tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
numbers = [n * 10 for n in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using list comprehension.

```
>>> n = 5                                                                                                               
>>> numbers = [i*10 for i in range(1,n+1)]                                                                              
>>> numbers                                                                                                             
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]                                                                                                    
>>>
```

This could work.

Answer (score 0):

```
N=100
numbers = [(i+1)*10 for i in range(N)]
print(numbers)
```

Try this