# Python index out of range exception

Tags: python, list, indexoutofrangeexception

I've tried this:

```
x = []
for i in range(5)
    x[i] = 0
print(x)
```

But it gives index out of range exception Why?

Comment: x is python list and not array. If you want to append the values to x, you can x.append(i) , or you can also initialize the list with fixed size and use the assignment as mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size

Comment: @Yousef if solved question please marked as an answer will help me and others too in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created an empty list `x = []` (not an array) and in a line `x[i] = 0` where you are trying to assign element `0` with `index=0` which does not exist at the time of initialization, here in your case it will be the first iteration of `for` loop with `i=0`.

Here is the example :

```
>>> x = []
>>> x[0] = 0
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    x[0] = 0
 IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

It will not allow you to assign element with index to an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is not any value in list that's why
In this case you have to use append

like

```
x = []
for i in range(5)
    x.append(0) #x[i] = 0 
print(x)
```

remove this line `x[i] = 0` and put `x.append(0)`

Comment: or `list(range(5))`

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `index out of range exception` because there is nothing in your list. If you want to loop 5 times and set `x[i] = 0` there has to be a `x[i]` first.