# How to insert values into an index that is out of range in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to build a 2-dimensial array which will be used to write values to a CSV file. At the point I am at, the array looks like

```
[['Filename', 'Date', 'Message']]
```

Those are the header rows. I need to be able to make a new 2D array which will have my new values placed in the correct indexes.
For example,

```
    my_list_of_csv_readings[index_row][0] = "file1.txt"
    my_list_of_csv_readings[index_row][1] = "04/27/2021"
    my_list_of_csv_readings[index_row][2] = "Hello World"
```

As you can see, I am just trying to add the values to the 2D array but assigning them to the indexes. The desired 2D array after inserting values would be:

```
[["Filename", "Date", "Message"], ["file1.txt", "04/27/2021", "New Message"]]
```

How can I ignore the fact that the index is out range and create a new list with the desired output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size
Does this solve your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't ignore it.  If you need to add rows, you need to use `append` or `extend`.  If you need random access, then you need a `dict`, not a `list`.

```
    my_list_of_csv_readings.append( ["file1.txt","04/27/2021"."Hello World"] )
```

Or, if you insist:

```
    my_list_of_csv_readings.append( [] )
    my_list_of_csv_readings[-1].append("file1.txt")
    my_list_of_csv_readings[-1].append("04/27/2021")
    my_list_of_csv_readings[-1].append("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be your prefered solution but it works:

```
lst = [['value', 'value', 'value']]

lst.append(['value'])
lst[1].append('other value')
lst[1].append('third value')
print(lst)

# prints: [['value', 'value', 'value'], ['value', 'other value', 'third value']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the append method to add the values:

```
a = [['Filename', 'Date', 'Message']]
a.append(["file1.txt", "04/27/2021", "New Message"])
print(a)
```

Output:
`[['Filename', 'Date', 'Message'], ['file1.txt', '04/27/2021', 'New Message']]`