# Create an empty list in Python with certain size using type hints

Tags: python, list, type-hinting

I want to use Python type hinting correctly when initializing an empty list

i was expecting this to work:

```
my_var: List[Path] = [None] * 1000
```

at least my IDE gives the error:

```
Expected type 'List[Path]', got 'List[None]' instead
```

Is there a correct way to use type hinting in this situation?

Comment: Use `List[Optional[Path]]`

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size Hope it helps!

Comment: `my_var: List[Path] = [None] * 1000` is a lie. You are saying your list is a list of `Path` objects. It isn't. It is a list of `None`, why would you *expect* this to work? Your list isn't empty at all. An empty list is just `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) type constructor.

```
from typing import Optional

my_var: List[Optional[Path]] = [None] * 1000
```

You could also have used `List[Union[Path, None]]`, though this is cleaner. In Python 3.10, you will be able to write `List[Path | None]`.

Answer (score -1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[None for x in range(1000)]
```

Comment: This does the same thing as `[None] * 1000`.

Comment: I thought he wanted a list with 1000 Nones in it.

Comment: yes and gives same problem with type hints

Comment: So what do you actually want a list of?