# How to unpack list with unknown number elements and replace the others variables by None

Tags: python, arraylist

if I have a list, say:

```
tags= ["ff", "uu", "ss"]
```

However, I do not know how assign element liste to variable, knowing that the number of elements in the list is variable and i want to assign a None to tag4 and tag5

```
tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 , tag5 = tags
```

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```py
tags= ["ff", "uu", "ss"]
tag_vars={}

for i in range(len(tags)):
    tag_vars[f"tag{i+1}"] = tags[i]

print(tag_vars)
print(tag_vars["tag1"])
print(tag_vars["tag2"])
print(tag_vars["tag3"])
```

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this:

```py
tags= ["ff", "uu", "ss", None, None]
tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4 , tag5 = tags
```

Some explanation - if you have a fixed number of elements in the array, you can fill the rest with `None` values.

This works well for prototyping and small arrays but if you are working with ML and other fancy things, I suggest using `numpy` and or `pandas` for this sort of manipulations.

output is as follows:

```py
In [6]: tag1
Out[6]: 'ff'

In [7]: tag2
Out[7]: 'uu'

In [8]: tag3
Out[8]: 'ss'

In [9]: tag4

In [10]: tag5

In [11]: tag5 is None
Out[11]: True
```

Here's another way to do it:
initalize a list with your fixed number say 5 like and only place items in the particular indices, like so:

```py
n [16]: l = [None] * 5

In [17]: l
Out[17]: [None, None, None, None, None]

In [18]: l[0] = 'foo'

In [19]: l
Out[19]: ['foo', None, None, None, None]
```

original answer: [Create an empty list in Python with certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-in-python-with-certain-size)