# is there a more efficient way to make a grid for bool values

Tags: python

I am trying to make a grid to store bool variables kinda like mine sweeper and i would like to find a better way
So far i have a very inefficient way of just declaring like 15 lists with the values set to false like this

```
A = [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this

Comment: Do you need a 2 dimesional list
e.g. `grid = [[False] * 15 for _ in range(15)]`

Comment: Use a Numpy 2D arrary and you can access any element by row, column. You can fill the whole array with one value or whatever mix you want.

Comment: Related (perhaps duplicate) [Comprehension to instantiate a boolean 2D array?](/q/39015925/15497888)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create an empty list with certain size in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712002/create-an-empty-list-with-certain-size-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can efficiently create a list of the same value with:

```
A = [False]*15
```

However, more code is required to extend this into a grid. Instead, you could use NumPy to create a grid of False (True) values by using np.zeros (np.ones). For example, a 3x4 grid of False values can be created with:

```
grid = np.zeros((3, 4), dtype=bool)

>> [[False False False False]
>>  [False False False False]
>>  [False False False False]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a 2D array for that:

```
array = [
    [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
    [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
    ...
]
```

This can also be created using a list comp:

```
array = [[False] * 15 for _ in range(15)]
```