# Accessing list items in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm attempting to create a data structure that keeps track of occurrences per month over a number of years. I have determined a dictionary of lists to be the best option. I want to create something like this structure (year: list of twelve integers representing occurrences per month):

```
yeardict = {
'2007':[0,1,2,0,3,4,1,3,4,0,6,3]
'2008':[0,1,2,0,3,4,1,3,5,0,6,3]
'2010':[7,1,3,0,2,6,0,6,1,8,1,4]
}
```

I am taking as an input, a dictionary that looks like this:

```
monthdict = {
'2007-03':4,
'2007-05':2,
'2008-02':8
etc.
}
```

I have my code loop through the second dictionary, first paying attention to the first 4 characters in the key (the year) and if that is NOT in the dictionary, then I initialize that key along with the value of twelve blank months in a list form: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], then change the value of the item in that list of the position of the month to whatever the value is. If the year is in the dictionary, then I just want to set the item in the list to equal the value that month.
My question is how do I access and set a specific item in a list within a dictionary. I am running into a number of errors which are not particularly helpful to google.

here is my code:

```
    yeardict = {}
    for key in sorted(monthdict):
        dyear = str(key)[0:4]
        dmonth = str(key)[5:]
        output += "year: "+dyear+" month: "+dmonth
        if dyear in yeardict:
            pass
#            yeardict[str(key)[0:4]][str(key)[5:]]=monthdict(key)                
        else:
            yeardict[str(key)[0:4]]=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
#            yeardict[int(dyear)][int(dmonth)]=monthdict(key)
```

The two lines that are commented out are where I want to actually set the values, and they introduce one of two errors when I add them to my code:
1. 'dict' is not callable
2. KeyError: 2009

Let me know if I can clarify anything. Thank you for looking.

Comment: `monthdict(key)` should be `monthdict[key]`

Comment: What is `tabhash` in your code, do you mean `yeardict`?

Comment: @F.J yes, sorry I changed the variable name in order to make things clearer and forgot to change it everywhere.

Comment: also, shouldn't it be `tabhash[dyear][int(dmonth)]=monthdict[key]`?

Comment: @Logan I get " TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str " when I make that change.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Look at my implementation and it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I would write this:

```
yeardict = {}
for key in monthdict:
    try:
        dyear, dmonth = map(int, key.split('-'))
    except Exception:
        continue  # you may want to log something about the format not matching
    if dyear not in yeardict:
        yeardict[dyear] = [0]*12
    yeardict[dyear][dmonth-1] = monthdict[key]
```

Note that I assumed that January in your date format is `01` not `00`, if that is not the case just use `dmonth` instead of `dmonth-1` in the last line.

Comment: +1, but could be shortened further to avoid the `if` statement by using `yeardict.setdefault(year, [0]*12)[dmonth-1] = monthdict[key]`

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you for fixing my problem and making it look much neater!

Comment: I ran this on some of my larger actual (monthdict) dictionaries, and they return: "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" Any ideas where to start debugging? Some answers say to append, rather than set equal ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/indexerror-list-assignment-index-out-of-range ), but that wouldn't work in my case where ordering matters.

Comment: @MilesLincoln Any chance you have 13 or higher as a month value?

Comment: @Nisan.H That would be shorter, but it may also unnecessarily create a lot of unused lists.

Comment: @F.J Right. I didn't consider that earlier.

Comment: @F.J that's possible. I'll look carefully through my code to see if that's the case. in the meantime, can I add something like this to bypass the error:  "if dmonth not in range(1,13):
            break" after the exception?

Comment: @MilesLincoln Yeah a check like that would probably be a good idea.  I would probably put something like `assert dmonth in range(1, 13)` at the end of the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
defaultlist = 12*[0]
years = {}
monthdict = {
'2007-03':4,
'2007-05':2,
'2008-02':8
}

for date, val in monthdict.items():
    (year, month) = date.split("-")
    occurences = list(years.get(year, defaultlist))
    occurences[int(month)-1] = val
    years[year] = occurences
```

*edit* actually, defaultdict won't help. Re wrote answer to just do a default get and make a copy of that list

Answer (score 0):

Does this have the behavior you want?

```
>>> yeardict = {}
>>> monthdict = {
... '2007-03':4,
... '2007-05':2,
... '2008-02':8 }
>>> for key in sorted(monthdict):
...     dyear = str(key)[0:4]
...     dmonth = str(key)[5:]
...     if dyear in yeardict:
...         yeardict[dyear][int(dmonth)-1]=monthdict[key]
...     else:
...         yeardict[dyear]=[0]*12
...         yeardict[dyear][int(dmonth)-1]=monthdict[key]
... 
>>> yeardict
{'2008': [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '2007': [0, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
>>>
```