# Error in exponential PDF

Tags: python-2.7, probability-density

I need to complete the function `exponentialPDF` but get an error:

`'IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0'`

The function looks like this:

```
def uniformPDF(x,a=0.0,b=4.0):
    p = 1.0/(b-a)*ones((len(x),))
    p[x<a] = 0.0
    p[x>b] = 0.0
    return(p)

def exponentialPDF(x,a=1.0):
"""
Call:
   p = exponentialPDF(x,a)
Input argument:
   vals: float (array)
Output argument:
   p: float (array)
Examples:
   In[1]:  exponentialPDF([1,2],3)
   Out[1]: array([ 0.14936121,  0.03332699])
"""
    p = a * exp(-a*x)
    p[x<0] = 0.0
    return(p)
```

Can someone help me with the error?

Comment: can you point out the line in which you get the error when you run the code??

Comment: It is this line: p[x<0] = 0.0

Comment: @EdSmith Smith Yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the list you are passing in to your function is empty. Read about python lists and see the following post:
[IndexError: list assignment index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/indexerror-list-assignment-index-out-of-range)

I found the function works using numpy array, e.g.  p = exponentialPDF(np.array([1,2]),3). Hope this help, you should check out the SO [homework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.%20Sounds%20like) post and ask again if you're still stuck.

EDIT: As you are using numpy, I would add an explicit convert to numpy array in the function as follows:

```
def exponentialPDF(x,a=1.0):
    """
    Call:
       p = exponentialPDF(x,a)
    Input argument:
       vals: float (array)
    Output argument:
        p: float (array)
    Examples:
       In[1]:  exponentialPDF([1,2],3)
       Out[1]: array([ 0.14936121,  0.03332699])
    """
    if type(x) is list:
        x = array(x)

    p = a * exp(-a*x)
    p[x<0] = 0.0
    return(p)
```

Hopefully this will fix your problem and you can use the function as needed (assuming returning a numpy array from the function is okay).

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. I tried it with the first post you mentioned but it still won't work. And yes, you're right that p = exponentialPDF(np.array([1,2]),3) works, I already wrote an email to the assistants if they wrote the function wrong. We have on top of our function these and are not allowed to import more:                                                 from numpy import *
from scipy import stats
from scipy.special import gammaln
from pylab import *          Is there maybe another way to solve this problem? Thanks also for the hint concerning the homework post.

Comment: In which case, I would suggest adding a conversion to numpy array in the function, I've edited my answer. Also, I know it's not your code but generic, import * syntax is not recommended as you can get conflicts between modules

Comment: Thanks a lot! They also have a mistake in their example, because if I try exponentialPDF(([1,2]),3) then the right answer comes out, but if I try it without the brackets as given in the example: exponentialPDF([1,2],3), then the values are slightly different.

Comment: Great, glad it worked! Typically in python, using (1,2) gives tuples and [1,2] lists. It's strange, using ([]) appears to give a different answer for you -- I get the same list from ([1,2]) as [1,2] and neither form works for me with your original function. It may be that () has been redefined to convert to a numpy array in your case...