# Delete last characters of a series of strings

Tags: python, string

Say I have an array of thousands of colours:

```
x=[blue, red, green,...]
```

How do I delete the last character(s) of each string so x1 would be [blu, re, gree,...]

I tried this:

```
x1=[]
for i in range (0,len(x)):
    x1[i]=x[i:-1]
```

The error I get is: list assignment index out of range

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you need this in place or require a new array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the error because `x1` is an empty list. The first iteration tries to assign to `x1[0]` which doesn't exist hence the `IndexError`.

Assuming `x` is a list of strings a more pythonic way would be to not use any indexes at all:

```
x1 = [color[:-1] for color in x]
```

Answer (score 3):

If `x` is a list of strings, then `x[i]` is a string. If you want all but the last character of that string, it is `x[i][:-1]`.

So you can write

```
x1 = []
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    x1.append(x[i][:-1])
```

or you could shorten that to

```
x1 = [colour[:-1] for colour in x]
```

Comment: List comprehensions shouldn't use an arbitrary letter; where possible they should use meaningful identifiers.

Comment: The first thing gives me the same error, the second one works.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ["blue", "red", "green"]

print [i[:-1] for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is the best way to solve your problem:

```
x = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
new_x = [color[:-1] for color in x]
```

But you can also achieve the result using `map` function:

```
x = ['blue', 'red', 'green']
new_x = list(map(lambda color: color[:-1], x))
```

I'm not sure which way is better on performance, but since nobody mention `map` so...

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got the error because of this reason 
[IndexError: list assignment index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/indexerror-list-assignment-index-out-of-range)

Hence you need to use .append to get this working.