# NameError on Python 3.7/ List assignment index Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

Before Anything this is my first time asking a question here so if there's Something wrong with the format of the question I'm sorry about that.

So basically This is a code that is supposed to get a list of numbers, and a number from user and check to see if the second input is equal to any of the elements of the list, then put those element index numbers in a new list and print it.

The thing is the error is saying 'a' is not defined but if I define it before the for loop like this:

> a=[]

or

```
a=list()
```

I get this:

```
a[k]= c
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Here's the code:

```
x = eval(input('list'))
y = eval(input('number'))
k=0
c=0
for i in x:
    if y==i:
        a[k]= c
        k+=1
    c+=1
print(a)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndexError: list assignment index out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/indexerror-list-assignment-index-out-of-range)

Comment: Are you wanting to just `append` to `a`? You can't assign to arbitrary indices that don't already have an element.

Comment: Of course, the variable `a` *must be defined before you use it*. The issue here is that when you index into a list, your index must be in-bounds. If you want to *add an element to the list*, you should use an appropriate mutator method, in this case, `.append`

Comment: @ Carcigenicate yes I was, for some reason didn't think of appending it.

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga thanks that does it.

Answer (score 0):

A list in python doesn't support index assignment. - Therefore the indices will always be numeric depending on the position 0, 1, n.

To add use `append`, to have a hash map use a `dict`.

Comment: "A list in python doesn't support index assignment" of course it does, the indices must simply be in range

Comment: yeah appending did it. Although for some reason I remember my python prof saying it's possible to do this in a loop without even defining the 'a' list outside the loop.Anyways Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga care to give an example?

Comment: You can define it in the loop of course. - but there's no other way I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
a[k]= c
```

You can use

```
a.append(c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Cheers!