# I have this very long piece of code that defines a list using x[0]=2 and so on in python 3.7. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

This is what my code is at the moment and I was wondering if I can assign list values like this.(I'm making a quote generator.)

```
import random as random
quotes = [] 
authors = [] 
quotes[0] = "I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time." 
authors[0] = "Charles Schulz" 
quotes[1] = "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it."
```

...

````
authors[5577] = "Henry David Thoreau" 
quotes[5578] = "Sometimes the cards we are dealt are not always fair. However you must keep smiling and moving on." 
authors[5578] = "Tom Jackson"
x=random.randint(2,5577)
for y in range(0,5579,1):
    print(quotes[y]+" "+author[y])```
````

Comment: Did you read the error message? It explains why this doesn't work.

Comment: line 5, in <module>
    quotes[1] = "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it."
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: That is what it is showing.

Comment: *list assignment index out of range* means you are trying to assign to a list, but the index you used is not an index in the list. The error occurs on `quotes[0]`, unless your code is different to what you posted here. The index `0` is out of range because the list is empty, so it does not have an index 0.

Comment: initialize your quotes and authors list ie, `quotes = [None] * 5579` `authors = [None] * 5579` . Then assign to the index.

Comment: Yes, that's why it doesn't work. `quotes[0]` assumes there is already a first element in it, and therefore gives an `IndexError`.

Comment: _Why doesn’t it work?_ In what way does it not work? Always share the entire error message, and a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this iterative list-growing code give IndexError: list assignment index out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/why-does-this-iterative-list-growing-code-give-indexerror-list-assignment-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting index out of range error since you are trying to access elements from an empty array. You can either initialize the author and quotes list:

```
authors = [None] * 5579
quotes = [None] * 5579
```

or a better way to add elements to list would be using the `append` method.

```
authors = []
quotes = []

quotes.append("I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time.") 
authors.append("Charles Schulz")

...
quotes.append("Sometimes the cards we are dealt are not always fair. However you must keep smiling and moving on.") 
authors.append("Tom Jackson")


for author, quote in zip(authors,quotes):
    print("{} {}".format(author, quote))
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, if you create an empty list, you can't assign values with the `[]` operator, that's for referencing elements that already exist inside the list (so you can update or read them). For adding new values to an empty list we use the `append` method like this:

```py
quotes = []
quotes.append("I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time.")

print(quotes[0])
>>> "I have a new philosophy. I'm only going to dread one day at a time."
```

You can now modify it because it exists:

```py
quotes[0] =  "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it." 
print(quotes[0])
>>>  "Reality is the leading cause of stress for those in touch with it."
```

If you try to access index `1` it will give you an `IndexError` because it only has index `0` (in my example).

Answer (score 1):

From [more on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), the `append()` function suggests a roundabout alternative to what you're trying to do:

```
>>> quotes = []
>>> quotes[0:] = ["first quote"]
>>> quotes[1:] = ["second quote"]
>>> quotes
['first quote', 'second quote']
```

This requires that both left hand and right hand sides be lists, and makes sure that you can't access lists that haven't had anything assigned to them yet.

As I mentioned in the comment above, `IndexError` comes from the list not having that element, which prevents one from mistakenly doing something like `quotes[55]` and expecting it to work too early on.

Comment: The `append` documentation says this is equivalent, but does not *suggest* it as an alternative. I believe it is only in the docs as a way of specifying `append`'s behaviour more formally. I hope nobody reads this and thinks it is a sensible way to write code.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it's sensible, but it's what looks the most like what was suggested by OP.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `quotes[0]` and so on, while `quotes` being empty, does not contain an index 0, 1, etc. You should use `append()` function instead, to add elements to your list.

Or, if you really want to use `quotes[0]` and so on, then do

```
quotes = [None] * 5579
```

or

```
quotes = [''] * 5579
```

at the start of the program.