# Assigning Values to Dictionaries versus Lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Why does this work...

```
ASET = {}
ASET["X"] = "HELLO"
print(ASET)
```

But this not work...

```
ASET = []
ASET[0] = "HELLO"
print(ASET)
```

The first will result in:

```
{'X': 'HELLO'}
```

The second will generate the error:

```
 IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-45-c521155a114d> in <module>
       1 ASET = []
 ----> 2 ASET[0] = "HELLO"
       3 print(ASET)

 IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this iterative list-growing code give IndexError: list assignment index out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/why-does-this-iterative-list-growing-code-give-indexerror-list-assignment-index)

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but there is a package for that https://github.com/carlosescri/DottedDict

Answer (score 1):

When you reference to an index in empty list, that index does not exist at that moment. To add values to a list (**empty too**) use `.append()`:

```
ASET = []
ASET.append("HELLO")
print(ASET)
```

The other syntax can be used if you have something already at that index in list:

```
ASET = ['World']
ASET[0] = "HELLO"
print(ASET)
```