# I get this error: Typeerror list indices must be integers or slices, not str. Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a leveling system and I get the same error: IndexError: list assignment index out of range
Here is my code where the error occurs:

```
async def update_data(users, user):
if not user.id in users:
    users[user.id] = {}
    users[user.id]['experience'] = 1
    users[user.id]['level'] = 1
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/why-does-this-iterative-list-growing-code-give-indexerror-list-assignment-index

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your "users" is list type. I could recreate the error like this:

```
class userino():
    def __init__(self): self.id=1


user = userino()
users = []
users[user.id] = {}
```

console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python38_Workspace/test/te.py", line 8, in <module>
    users[user.id] = {}
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

with list types you should use append or change the type of users to dict