# why list assignment giving out of indexError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def update_array(incoming: tuple, output: list = []):
  for index, element in enumerate(incoming):
    output[index] = incoming[index]
    if index % 2 == 0:
        incoming[index] = incoming[index] / 2
  return output
```

In the above example, line 3 is giving out of index error

```
output[index] = incoming[index]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

i couldn't understand why the error occurring, trying to learn tuple and list.
Thank you:-)

Comment: How are you calling this? If `output` is the default empty list (by the way see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761), then you can't assign to _any_ index in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this iterative list-growing code give IndexError: list assignment index out of range? How can I repeatedly add (append) elements to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/why-does-this-iterative-list-growing-code-give-indexerror-list-assignment-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for the error is that `output` is an empty list and occupies no space. You can append to the list instead.

```py
output.append(incoming[index])
```