# IndexError: list assignment index out of range - python list

Tags: python

I am trying to assign values to a list at `i`th position.

```
coords = [] 

lat = 37.312312
long = -118.31231

coords[0] = lat
coords[1] = long
```

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/d0/gnksqzwn2fn46fjgrkp6045c0000gn/T/ipykernel_56868/3062929082.py in <module>
      4 long = -118.31231
      5 
----> 6 coords[0] = lat
      7 coords[1] = long

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this iterative list-growing code give IndexError: list assignment index out of range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/why-does-this-iterative-list-growing-code-give-indexerror-list-assignment-index)

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you could do this if you REALLY don’t want to use append:

```
coords = [0,0] 

lat = 37.312312
long = -118.31231

coords[0] = lat
coords[1] = long
```