# what should i do, i am trying to run this code but it is giving this error

Tags: python, multi-select

here is my code, i dont know what i am missing here. can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

# Create your models here.
class Car(models.Model):

    state_choice = (
        ('AL', 'Alabama'),
        ('AK', 'Alaska'),
        ('AZ', 'Arizona'),
        ('AR', 'Arkansas'),
        ('CA', 'California'),
        ('CO', 'Colorado'),
        ('CT', 'Connecticut'),
        ('DE', 'Delaware'),
        ('DC', 'District Of Columbia'),
        ('FL', 'Florida'),
        ('GA', 'Georgia'),
        ('HI', 'Hawaii'),
        ('ID', 'Idaho'),
        ('IL', 'Illinois'),
        ('IN', 'Indiana'),
        ('IA', 'Iowa'),
        ('KS', 'Kansas'),
        ('KY', 'Kentucky'),
        ('LA', 'Louisiana'),
        ('ME', 'Maine'),
        ('MD', 'Maryland'),
        ('MA', 'Massachusetts'),
        ('MI', 'Michigan'),
        ('MN', 'Minnesota'),
        ('MS', 'Mississippi'),
        ('MO', 'Missouri'),
        ('MT', 'Montana'),
        ('NE', 'Nebraska'),
        ('NV', 'Nevada'),
        ('NH', 'New Hampshire'),
        ('NJ', 'New Jersey'),
        ('NM', 'New Mexico'),
        ('NY', 'New York'),
        ('NC', 'North Carolina'),
        ('ND', 'North Dakota'),
        ('OH', 'Ohio'),
        ('OK', 'Oklahoma'),
        ('OR', 'Oregon'),
        ('PA', 'Pennsylvania'),
        ('RI', 'Rhode Island'),
        ('SC', 'South Carolina'),
        ('SD', 'South Dakota'),
        ('TN', 'Tennessee'),
        ('TX', 'Texas'),
        ('UT', 'Utah'),
        ('VT', 'Vermont'),
        ('VA', 'Virginia'),
        ('WA', 'Washington'),
        ('WV', 'West Virginia'),
        ('WI', 'Wisconsin'),
        ('WY', 'Wyoming'),
    )

    year_choice = []
    for r in range(2000, (datetime.now().year+1)):
        year_choice.append((r,r))

    features_choices = (
        ('Cruise Control', 'Cruise Control'),
        ('Audio Interface', 'Audio Interface'),
        ('Airbags', 'Airbags'),
        ('Air Conditioning', 'Air Conditioning'),
        ('Seat Heating', 'Seat Heating'),
        ('Alarm System', 'Alarm System'),
        ('ParkAssist', 'ParkAssist'),
        ('Power Steering', 'Power Steering'),
        ('Reversing Camera', 'Reversing Camera'),
        ('Direct Fuel Injection', 'Direct Fuel Injection'),
        ('Auto Start/Stop', 'Auto Start/Stop'),
        ('Wind Deflector', 'Wind Deflector'),
        ('Bluetooth Handset', 'Bluetooth Handset'),
    )

    door_choices = (
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5'),
        ('6', '6'),
    )

    car_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(choices=state_choice, max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.IntegerField(('year'), choices=year_choice)
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    description = RichTextField()
    car_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    car_photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    car_photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    car_photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    car_photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    features = MultiSelectField(choices=features_choices)
    body_style = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    engine = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    transmission = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    interior = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    miles = models.IntegerField()
    doors = models.CharField(choices=door_choices, max_length=10)
    passengers = models.IntegerField()
    vin_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    milage = models.IntegerField()
    fuel_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    no_of_owners = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_title
```

here is my result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/django/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/django/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/admin/django/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/admin/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 394, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/admin/django/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/django/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/admin/django/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/admin/django/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Car Project/cars/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Car(models.Model):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/Car Project/cars/models.py", line 105, in Car
    features = MultiSelectField(choices=features_choices)
  File "/Users/admin/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/multiselectfield/db/fields.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.validators[0] = MaxValueMultiFieldValidator(self.max_length)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this iterative list-growing code give IndexError: list assignment index out of range? How can I repeatedly add (append) elements to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653533/why-does-this-iterative-list-growing-code-give-indexerror-list-assignment-index)

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the error message really carefully.
You will see that there is a problem in line 105 of models.py
`features = MultiSelectField(choices=features_choices)`

`features_choices` is passed into `MultiSelectField()` and after this the following error happens:
`IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

A value is trying to be set in a list, however at a position that is out of range. perhaps this list has a length of 5 and something is being put on position 7, this is not possible.
The exact code where this happens is not included in your answer, but maybe if you have another look you will find the problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Put link this :**
feature=MultiSelectField(choices=features_choices,max_choices=5, max_length=200)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).